# Saving multiple instances of same form in django

Tags: django, forms, model, save, multiple-instances

in my template user can add (with add button :) ) another instance of same form (empty one ofc ) but when I click Submit(save) ony last one entered is being saved. 
views.py:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

template:

```
<form action="{{ action }}" class="form-horizontal form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {% csrf_token %}

{% if object.id %}
  <legend>Edit Object2</legend>
{% else %}
  <legend>Add Object2</legend>
{% endif %}

  {{ form }}

  <div class="objects2">
      {% for objects2_form in form %}
        <div id="objects2-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">


        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
   <a href="#" id="add-object2" class="btn btn-info add-object2" >Add object2</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**
I've decided it's easier to post one object at the time and on save render same page. Problem i have now is that only 1(last) form is shown on page instead of all. (All are saved in db). And how to show empty form as last?

**EDIT2:**
I've managed to show all:

```
object2 = object2Model.objects.all()
        return  render_to_response('xxx.html', 
                          {'form': form, 'object2': object2}, context_instance = RequestContext(self.request))
```

So only 1 thing remains.. How to show empty form?? (without using formset)

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attributes of your form's data tags will be repeated. So, for example, the last `<input type="text" name="firstname">` will overwrite all previous fields with the same `name="firstname"` name.

There is not really any built-in way to have the same form fields render twice inside the same `<form/>` DOM element.

I would render the `forms.Form` instances into different `<form/>` elements and have one joined submit `<button onclick="submitAllForms()">` that calls a Javascript to submit all the existing `<forms/>` objects.

That would be the cleanest way, especially for your server-side models.

So, on-load, you could simply select the empty form DOM element and copy it. Then, when the user selects to add another instance of the form, you can use that copy as a template to add another form to the page. You could have any number of the same form that way, with no additional work.

Then when the user submits the form, simply select all the `<form>` DOM elements and call .sumbit() on each. And your server will only ever see regular `forms.Form` instances submitted.